# How do you nest backbone.js collections?

Tags: backbone.js

I have three arrays sitting in browser memory:

**students** = `[{studentID: x, firstName: x, lastName: x},{...}, {...}]`

**teachers** = `[{teacherName: x},{...}, {...}]`

**times** = `[{teacher: x, start: x, end: x},{...}, {...}]`

Here's what I need to happen:

1. render a drop-down menu of students
2. upon selecting a student, render a drop-down menu of that student's teachers
3. upon selecting a teacher, render a drop-down menu of that teacher's available time slots

I can create all three models, collections, and views using backbone.js, but I can't "connect" them. How do I nest *times* inside *teachers* inside *students*? Or is there a better way?

Keep in mind, no need to do a fetch, because the data is sitting in memory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this tutorial of cascading dropdowns

http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/07/25/cascading-select-boxes-with-backbone-js/

I think is what you are looking for.
and instead of fetch just reset your collections

```
this.collection.reset(anArray);
```

Comment: Yeah, I checked out that tutorial, and it seemed ok, but I had a problem with the .fetch(). So you're saying instead of fetching data, I can just reset the data with a new (or filtered) array?

Comment: yes, you already have it so just change the fetch parts for resets, perhaps you need to do additional filters, try the underscore functions to filter you arrays collections as you need.